# I am looking to find the sum of certain columns in my data set

Tags: r

I am looking to find the sum of certain columns in my dataset. currently it looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpeFR.png).

I want to find the column sum of everyone in X, Y and Z for each possible grid and month combination. 
Currently I have

```
xx<-data[data$Month=="November"&data$grid=="A3",]

fun<-by(xx[, 1:3],xx$grid, colSums,na.rm=T)
fun<-as.character(fun)

as.data.frame(fun,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

But this requires me to change the grid ref and month ref each time, is there a simpler way to do it without manually specifying which grids and months I want.

Comment: Just try `aggregate(data[,1:3], data[,4:5],FUN=sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr` after grouping by 'month', 'grid'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(month, grid) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

---

Or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~month + grid, data, FUN = sum)
```

---

Or using the OP's method

```
by(data[1:3], data[4:5], FUN = colSums)
```

Comment: Thanks, But I still can't get any of those to work. I can't use "dplr" on the version of R I am currently using and I downloaded the newest version but it is having trouble finding the command "group_by" even though it says I have successfully installed dplyr.

the aggregate function comes up with 
 in array(dim = extent, dimnames = namelist) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ngroup * (as.integer(index) - one) :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In ngroup * nlevels(index) : NAs produced by integer overflow"

Comment: @Fosulli  As you haven't showed any reproducible example in your post, it is difficult to comment.  Have you loaded the library?  i.e. `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it better. When running the code

data %>%
   group_by(month, grid) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum))

the error comes up that "sum" is not meaningful for factors. How do you specify that you want to sum columns x,y and z?

Comment: I figured it out, I had another factor variable in the dataset and it wouldn't work with the "sum" function. thank you for your help.